# Passing Paramters to TestNG XML file from Jenkins

Tags: java, xml, testing, jenkins, testng

I am trying to create a Jenkins jobs that will build an XML request for me, it will eventually be a tool.

I already have a number of Tests running using this system working with no issue but I want to be able to pass a parameter from Jenkins straight into the XML.

I can pass it into the Test using the Get System Property method.

My XML looks like this

```
<parameter name="env" value="xxx"/>
<parameter name="testName" value="Supplier: SKY Test"/>


<test name="multicom-test-sky">

    <!--Build Post URL from the following-->
    <parameter name="protocol" value="http://"/>
    <parameter name="env" value="xxxx"/>
    <parameter name="server" value="xxxx"/>
    <parameter name="port" value="xxx"/>
    <parameter name="endPoint" value="xxx"/>

    <!--Syndicator login-->
    <parameter name="syndicatorID" value="xxxxxxx"/>
    <parameter name="syndicatorPassword" value="xxxxxx"/>
    <parameter name="target" value="test"/>

    <!--Searching Parameters-->
    <parameter name="departure" value="LGW"/>
    <parameter name="destination" value="GVA"/>
    <parameter name="supplier" value="SKY"/>
    <parameter name="numOfAdults" value="2"/>
    <parameter name="numOfChildren" value="2"/>
    <parameter name="numOfInfants" value="0"/>
    <parameter name="startDate" value="20170318"/>
    <parameter name="endDate" value="20170318"/>
    <parameter name="minNumberofNights" value="7"/>
    <parameter name="maxNumberofNights" value="7"/>
    <parameter name="childOneAge" value="15"/>
    <parameter name="childTwoAge" value="10"/>

    <!--tests to run-->
    <classes>
        <class name="com.multicom.fab.api.EndToEndSimpleBooking"/>
    </classes>
</test>
```

I want to be able to pass the value of these parameters in from Jenkins and set them at this level so then they are passed to the test for execution.

Any ideas on how this is possible?

Appreciate the help in advanced

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TestNg can use system properties as parameters so, if you do not want to write any additional code - just run TestNG from command line in Jenkins and pass your parameters like `java -Dpath=$PATH org.testng.TestNG your.class.java`.

Better way is to use properties or run it via maven or gradle.

Comment: I am running this via maven, for what I was trying to achieve I tried a different approach in the end. But thanks for the help. I didn't need to pass any into the XML in the end.